# Multicast (or similar ) solution required for tomcat / servlet.

Tags: http, tomcat, servlets, apache-camel, multicast

I am working on a application, which is proposed to be a set of webapps (being called agent), running on tomcat 7, configured on different nodes. I have been tasked, to make these webapps(agent) discover each other automatically. The idea is, that each webapp(say agent X) , once up, will communicate a 'request pattern' to all the other webapps. Other webapps(say agents A, B, C) in turn will store this information ('request pattern') and will use these to route any matching request to agent X using http call.
I am looking for some option where in each webapp will have some component listening on particular port, and the agent X while registering itself will send a multicast request to all the nodes on that particular port.
I think apache camel might be useful here.. but I am not sure. 
It will be great if some body can tell the technical viability of this approach, or any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was that you could use apache httpd and the mod_proxy_loadbalancer to balance all requests over the available nodes. You can define different balancers for any kind of agents. Requests will be send to the balancer and the balancer will route it to any available node.

Comment: Thanks @magomi. This is not about only load balancing, instead different requests are to be sent different webapps(agent) based on the 'request pattern' initially passed.

Comment: RequestPatterns could be defined in the apache config for a certain balancer.

The idea with apache was only a quick thought. :)

(BTW - maybe you should check your homepage phoneynk.com)

Comment: Thanks @magomi. This is not about only load balancing, instead different requests are to be sent different webapps(agent) based on the 'request pattern' initially passed. Suppose agent X is for handling 'Order' request, then once it is starting up, it will communicate to all other webapps that X agent can handle 'Order' request, then only 'order' type of request will be sent. Also I am looking for solution using Java and related technologies.

Comment: Sorry for my last comment [I am new to stackoverflow :( ] I will sure evaluate apache httpd, but it will be great if some one can suggest a 'java/tomcat' solution. (and yes.. I have not looked into the issues of phonynk.com since long)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a messaging than a routing problem. Add Camel if you need complex routing or adapting to legacy protocols.

This looks like a classic publish and subscribe use case. You can do it with any messaging technology. Look at JMS - ActiveMQ is what Camel uses, or AMQP - I've used RabbitMQ very successfully for this, both use the "topic" paradigm for this, a quick search found this as an example: http://jmsexample.zcage.com/index2.html. Or Jabber.

Julian